# How can I put <system-out> tag into <testcase> tag in junit xml which is generated by testng

Tags: jenkins, gradle, junit, testng

Currently, I'm using TestNG + gradle for my automation project. And I run my tests by jenkins through gradle command "gradle test". In my build.gradle file I input "useDefaultListeners = true" to my test tasks (and after run the command "gradle test", It will have a junit reports xml file (Which I will use to export the result on the jenkins by junit plugin). But the problem is all the log of test cases is the same, and I found out that the problem is because in the junit report xml file, the  tag is outside the  tag. For example:

```
<testcase classname="Clase Name" name="Test Case 1" time="0.415"/>
<system-out>
  Test Case 1's Console log goes here
</system-out>
<testcase classname="Clase Name" name="Test Case 2" time="0.415"/>
<system-out>
  Test Case s's Console log goes here
</system-out>
```

So Jenkins just get the first  tag (Test Case 1) and displays that to all the test case logs.
So how can I correct it, put the  tag inside the  tag for jenkins to displays the logs correctly

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out how to come over this issue. I have to write the gradle task which will edit the xml file to move the  tag to inside the  tag. The task will be run after the "gradle test" task

```
tasks.register('correctXML') {
doLast {
    def currentDir = new File("./build/reports/tests/test/junitreports")
    currentDir.eachFileRecurse (groovy.io.FileType.FILES) { file ->
        def originalFile = new XmlSlurper().parse(file.path)
        def finalFile = new XmlSlurper().parse(file.path)

        //Remove all <system-out> tag
        finalFile['system-out'].replaceNode{}

        //Append the <system-out> to <testcase> tag
        finalFile['testcase'].eachWithIndex { testCase,index ->
            testCase.appendNode(originalFile['system-out'][index])
        }

        //Write a file
        File result = new File(file.path)
        result.write XmlUtil.serialize(finalFile).toString()
    }
}
```

This is my temporary task's script (just make it works, hasn't refactored yet)